# dynamically get hidden field value without submitting form

Tags: javascript, php, html

my query is generating 3 result with three send enquiry button which send the value of there respective hidden field but all the time when i click send enquiry button i show me always the 1st company name in my javascript

here is my php..

```
  $adcategory=$_GET['category'];
  mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
  mysql_select_db('advertising site');
  $selectquery="select * from business_ads where company_category='$adcategory'";
  $result=mysql_query($selectquery)or die(mysql_error());
  $resultrows=mysql_num_rows($result);
  if($resultrows>=1)
  {
  echo"<p>$resultrows</p>";
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $companyname=$row['company_name'];?>
  <div id="ads">
  <p id="company_name" name="company_name"><?php echo $companyname?></p>
  <input type="hidden" name="hidden_company_name" value="<?php echo        
  $companyname>"id="hidden_name">   
  <input type="hidden" name="hidden_company_name" value="<?php echo $companyname ?    
  >"id="hidden_name">
  <center><input type="button" name="send_enquiry" id="send_enquiry" value="Send    
  Enquiry"       
  onclick="f1();"></center>
  <input type="submit"value="submit" name="submit_enquiry_form">

 </div>
 <?php
 }
 }
```

and here is my javascript

```
 function f1()
 {
 var comp_name=document.getElementById('hidden_name').value;
 var elements=comp_name;
 document.write(elements);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both these show there is no space between your closing quote and the id

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_company_name" value="<?php echo        
$companyname>"id="hidden_name">   
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_company_name" value="<?php echo $companyname ?    
>"id="hidden_name">
```

Also it is bad coding to have more than one element with the same ID. As you will never end up with the proper element when you try to reference it by ID.

If this is just going to be a hidden value that is not changed by javascript then simply doing this will provide the value into a js var.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var valueIwant="<?php echo $companyname; ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: sorry this is my typing mistake  and i used your suggestion but it is not working

Comment: I will need more info to help. Do you have a way we can see what is actually happening? jsfiddle or is this publicly accessible?

Comment: no i am working on a local host my problem is that when i get the values from the database and display them and when i click on send enquiry button it show me a dialog box with respective company name but it always show ist name of my database table no respective company name

Comment: can you make the ID of the actual hidden input you want more unique? `id="hidden_name_i_really_want"` `document.getElementById('hidden_name_i_really_want').value;`

Comment: please solve my problem can i give you my full script

Comment: post it on pastebin i'll see what i can do

Comment: now i make a simpler code for you please solve my problem my code produce 3 send enquiry button with 3 input field of different value

Comment: yes i paste my complete code in pastebin with title dynamic value in modal box